# Expression Changed after it has been checked Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling, upload, checked

I have this input for uploading a document, and i'm trying to check if it's empty to show an alert.

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" 
    (change)="onUpload($event)">
    <input type="text" #documentLink class="form-control" name="urlDocument" [value]="urlDocument | async">
</div>
<div *ngIf="!documentLink.value" class="alert alert-danger">
   Imaginea de coperta este necesara!
</div>
```

[image]

I have this error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.
```

I use this viewchild to take the value

```
@ViewChild('documentLink', {static: false}) inputDocumentLink : ElementRef;
```

and that's in my method for adding it in the database:

```
const link = this.inputDocumentLink.nativeElement.value;
...
```

Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: where you are setting documentLink?

Comment: I have something like this in my ts:     @ViewChild('documentLink', {static: false}) inputDocumentLink : ElementRef;

Comment: And i'm taking the value like this in my method:  const link = this.inputDocumentLink.nativeElement.value;

Comment: can you put your ts file above?

Comment: @Aakash Garg - From what I can see, `#documentLink` is set in the template.

Comment: @AndreeaPopa your method didn't come properly

Comment: Yes @ConnorsFan, the problem is after uploading the document, of course the input is no longer empty and it changed after it was checked once. Everything else works but i'm getting this error and idk how to get rid of it.

Comment: @Aakash Garg i didn't put all the method because that's not my problem, it works. I don't know how to check in the template without getting that error.

Comment: @AndreeaPopa find my answer below.

Comment: Please note that you could eliminate the exception while still using the `async` pipe.

Comment: @ConnorsFan how?

Comment: I posted an answer showing how to keep using the `async` pipe in your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is use of async pipe and refering that value below in the template.

Remove async pipe from template

In Ts have it like

```
public inputValue;
ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
}

public getData() {
   this.urlDocument.subscribe((res) => {
          this.inputValue = res;
   });
 }
```

HTML :-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" 
    (change)="onUpload($event)">
    <input type="text" #documentLink class="form-control" name="urlDocument" [value]="inputValue">
</div>
<div *ngIf="!inputValue" class="alert alert-danger">
   Imaginea de coperta este necesara!
</div>
```

**Reason :-** while navigating through template your url document was undefined, when it angular's another life cycle hook rechecked the template it got changed because observable emitted value. Because in normal ng serve angular does every change detection twice to let you know irregularities in your code. try running ng serve --prod and you won't get this error. But you should go with approach i gave as this error is given to avoid such irregularities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `*ngIf` condition depends on a property of the input element that is updated with data binding. To avoid the exception, you should refer to the original data instead of the element property.

The code below shows how to keep using the `async` pipe without repeating it. The async result is stored in a `doc` object set in the `*ngIf` condition of an encompassing `ng-container` (creating an object ensures that the condition is always `true`). We then use `doc.url` as the value in the `input` and in the `*ngIf` condition of the `div` element.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ url: urlDocument | async } as doc">
  <div class="form-group">
    ...
    <input type="text" #documentLink [value]="doc.url" ...>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!doc.url" ...>
     Imaginea de coperta este necesara!
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-binding-ev5vlm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.